# Search box disappear by clicking outside the search box

Tags: jquery

I have done the search box by jQuery toggle.

```
jQuery('.menu-search .icon-search').toggle(
    function() {
        jQuery('.menu-search form').fadeIn( "first" );
    },
    function() {
        jQuery('.menu-search form').fadeOut( "first" );
    }
);
```

When i click the search icon, the search box appear and disappear when click on the search icon again. But i want to disappear when i click outside the search box. I tried for that, but it is not working.

```
jQuery('html').click(function (event) {
    jQuery('.menu-search form').fadeOut( "first" );
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

I know i can use the not(), But i tried that. it is also not working.
I have tried like this

```
jQuery('html').not('.search-form fieldset').click(function (event) {
    jQuery('.menu-search form').fadeOut( "first" );
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

This is the HTML for the script.

```
<li class="menu-search clearfix menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><i class="icon-search"></i><form action="http://mybebsite.com/" class="search-form clearfix" style="display: block;">
    <fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Go" class="submit">
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
        <input type="text" class="search-form-input text" name="s" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" value="Search">

    </fieldset>
</form>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code

```
jQuery('html').click(function (event) {
    jQuery('.menu-search form').fadeOut( "first" );
    event.stopPropagation();
})
jQuery('.menu-search form').click(function (event) {
    return false;
})
```

this way your search box will not disappear.